# JS - how to provide a smooth movement in x-direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to provide a smooth movement in x-direction. The Object A is supposed to be twice as fast as Object B. Somehow the movement of A does not look smooth.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3v8kp7j/1/)

JS

```
var ax = bx = 0;

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();



(function animloop(){
    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    render();
})();

function render() {
    ax+=4;
    $('.A').css("left", ax);

    bx++;
    $('.B').css("left", bx);
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty smooth to me. Mac OS 10.10 Chrome 42.0.2282.0

Comment: Its ok for me too on Win 7 Chrome 39

Comment: You can get the smoothest animation with `translate3d` in CSS as it's handled by the GPU, but I'm not sure how to best use it for what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want A to be 2x as fast as B, why are you adding 4x the pixels? 0,0 ... 1,4 ... 2,8 ... 3,12 ... 4,16 ...5,20.. It's linear, but it's 4x. As for "smoothness" it does seem to stutter a bit on initial load, but after reloading it seems ok. A more "natural" animation would be one that eases in slowly, speeds up, and then slows to a stop. Completely linear animations tend to look mechanical.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it smoother would be to take the time since last render:

```
var ax = bx = 0,
    start;

window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();



(function animloop(timestamp) {
    if (!start) {
        start = timestamp;
    }
    var progress = timestamp - start;

    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    render(progress);
})();

function render(progress) {
    $('.A').css("left", progress / 4);

    bx++;
    $('.B').css("left", progress / 16);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3v8kp7j/2/